# Understanding ServiceWorker registration

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm reading the ServiceWorker getting started docs https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers.

So first we register our ServiceWorker with the scope. So I did that as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting started with Service Worker</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}    

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and created a sw.js file and wrote a console.log inside sw.js

```
console.log("This is sw.js")
```

So when I access the index.html file the first time, that console.log is executed and ServiceWorker registration successful message is printed. But when I refresh the page second time, it only prints the message ServiceWorker registration successful. So why didn't it executed the console.log inside sw.js for the second time. I was expecting it to execute that console.log second time. Am I missing the point here?

Comment: Just FWIW, sometimes people get [service workers](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/) and general-purpose [web workers](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) confused. Are you sure you want a service worker for what you're doing? Service workers are a special kind of web worker used for managing page resources (for instance, offline apps).

Answer (score 4):

Service workers are scripts that are basically executed once (in background) when they are registered. If you need to execute some recurrent code, you need to use [service worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API):

> A service worker is an event-driven worker registered against an origin and a path.

The install event is called **asynchronously** after you call `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')`; that's why it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), to which you pass a `callback` function (the one with the content `console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful ...');`).

Comment: So when does that install event is actually fired I understand we are catching pages and other resources, but when does this install event actually fired.

Comment: So the install event is fired only one times, once the service worker is registred right?  @Wikiti

Comment: The MDN link answers my questions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: @MahtabAlam I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: So, if the <script> that contains the register code is followed by some other code that causes more network requests (eg another <script src="a.js"></script>, or <link rel="stylesheet">; there's not guarantee that 'a.js' triggers the 'fetch' even handler in the sw?

Answer (score 1):

A service worker is designed to sit in between your website and the network. So while you load your page initially, it runs the script once and installs the service worker if you have added an event to listen for installs.

Once that's done, you need to attach a listener to the 'fetch' event to capture all your requests inside your page.
So basically if you want to console.log every time a request is made, you can do the following:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  console.log(event);
})
```

Comment: Yes, but that is all done in parallel with the processing of index.html, so network requests can be made before the s/w has added the 'fetch' event handler...if so, they would miss any processing in the fetch handler (like being added to a cache, or whatever).